# AWS Elastic Search drop size abruptly

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch

We have a social like app, and we started using the AWS ElasticcSearch Service in production, but we started to have a problem with ES, the ES version is the 2.3.

The cluster configuration is:

- Data node: 2
- Data node types: m3.medium.elasticsearch
- Dedicated master instance count: 3
- Dedicated master instance type: t2.small.elasticsearch.
- Capacity of each data node: 50GB.

The problem is that in less than thirty minutes one of the node free storage size went from 9 GB to 0 GB, we did not know how this happened.

We have 4 types of documents, where one of them is a dynamic type, lets call it Group type, that is because every document of Group can have N fields that represents the friends of a Group.
Something like

```
{
  13: [1,2,3,4],
  5: [1,3,4],
  user_ids: [1,2,3,4,6,7],
  id: 1
}
```

This means that the users with ID 13 and 5 are friends with some of the users of the Group with ID 1.

So this document can grows according to the amount of users.

If anyone had or has the same problem, or just fully understand the Elastic Search architecture it would be awesome his help.

Indices info:

```
curl -XGET 'http://host/_cat/indices?v
health status index              pri rep docs.count docs.deleted store.size pri.store.size 
green  open   .kibana-4           1   1          5            0      1.9mb       1017.3kb 
green  open   X                   1   1    2259502        29575     57.5gb         28.7gb 
green  open   Y                   1   1     113156            0     21.7mb         10.8mb


curl -XGET 'http://host/_cat/nodes?v&h=host,id,ip,rp,hp,d,cpu,v,r,m,n
host     id     ip   rp hp    d    cpu v    r m  n       
x.x.x.x tIgm x.x.x.x 95  5  5.7gb   0 2.3.2 - m Shatter 
x.x.x.x puUF x.x.x.x 95  6  5.7gb   0 2.3.2 - m Justice 
x.x.x.x 1qZi x.x.x.x 97 54 17.7gb   7 2.3.2 d - Allatou 
x.x.x.x lcty x.x.x.x 97 60 17.7gb   8 2.3.2 d - Amergin 
x.x.x.x Nq1H x.x.x.x  5 15  5.7gb   0 2.3.2 - * Arkus
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: So your two data nodes are full basically, right? Also you should give more RAM to the OS as it seems you're assigning almost all the RAM to ES.

Comment: Yes, they are both full. The only thing that I can configure in AWS is changing the type of instance that we are using.

Comment: Well, you probably need to figure out what is filling your nodes... What client processes are sending data to your cluster?

Comment: @Val in the elasticsearch IRC recommends me to run forcemerge command, does it takes to long to run? Because I have read in the docs that the index stay blocked until the merge is completed

Comment: That's only going to solve the problem temporarily. If you're sending too much data to your cluster, you can either augment the storage size or send less information.

Comment: Yes, you are rigth. The only thing that I can rethink is the friend ID's that it can grows indefinitely

Comment: I don't think that's the only problem. With only 2 million documents, I can hardly imagine that you manage to fill 30 GB of storage space.

Comment: @Val what did you mean with the client ?
What happen if the update rate was very high during the time of the drop?

Comment: How do you index documents into your cluster?

Comment: We have a rails app, that uses the elasticsearch [gem](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-rails/tree/master/elasticsearch-model)

Comment: Then I would either monitor that client app to figure out why it's sending so much stuff into your cluster and/or augment the storage space for your index. Are you sure you don't have auto-generated ID which create new docs on each document updates?

Comment: @Val Every time I want to index a document I pass the id of the object.
I have run the forcemerge, the freeStorageSpace dropped from 8GB to 4.8GB, after a few minutes the storage established in 7GB.

Comment: How many documents per second/minute are you indexing?

Comment: How can I know? Is there a metric of that type in ES? I can only watch how the searcheableDocuments grows

Comment: Your client app is under your control, so you can certainly figure out what it's doing right?

Comment: When the app has the greatest traffic, we have a rate of 150 documents updates or creates per minute. 
What I do not understant is the decrease of the 1GB after doing the _forcemerge, do you have any idea?

Comment: That means you have a lot of updates of the same documents and that creates a big amount of deleted documents, see the `docs.deleted` count above. When running `_forcemerge` those deleted documents get wiped out.

Comment: I have already run the `_forcemerge` command, and now I have 1Gb less. Before running I had 29449 deleted documents, but after running the `_forcemerge` I have still remaining 19280 deleted documented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to resolve the problem.

My problem is known as [Mapping Explosion](https://www.elastic.co/blog/found-crash-elasticsearch#mapping-explosion)

Having variables keys in the mapping, like I had in the Group document type, will result on an evergrowing index.